# Link tables based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to pull values from 2 different tables based on the value of a column? For example, I have a table with a boolean column that either returns 0 or 1 depending on what the end user selects in our program. 0 means that I should pull in the default values. 1 means to use the user's data.

If my table `Table1` looked like this:

```
Case ID      Boolean
====================
    1              0
    2              1
    3              1
    4              0
    5              0
```

Then I would need to pull Case IDs 1,4,and 5's corresponding data from table `Default` and Case IDs 3 and 4's corresponding data from table `UserDef`. Then I would have to take these values, combine them, and reorder them by Case ID so I can preserve the order in the resulting table.

I am fairly inexperienced with SQL but I am trying to learn. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.CaseID
 ,CASE WHEN t1.Boolean = 1 THEN dt.Col1 ELSE ut.Col1 END AS Col1
 ,CASE WHEN t1.Boolean = 1 THEN dt.Col2 ELSE ut.Col2 END AS Col2 
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN DefaultTable dt ON dt.CaseID = t1.CaseID
LEFT JOIN UserDefTable ut ON ut.CaseID = t1.CaseID
ORDER BY t1.CaseID
```

You join on both tables and then use `CASE` in `SELECT` to choose from which one to display data.

**Option B:**

```
WITH CTE_Combo AS
(
   SELECT 0 as Boolean, * FROM Default     --replace * with needed columns
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 1 AS Boolean, * FROM UserDef     --replace * with needed columns
)
SELECT * FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN CTE_Combo c ON t.CaseID = c.CaseID AND t.Boolean = c.Boolean
ORDER BY t.CaseID
```

This might be even simpler - using CTE make a union of both tables adding artificial column, and then join CTE and your Table using both ID and flag column.

Comment: Thank you for the response. dt.Col1 and dt.Col2 are the corresponding data columns? What if I do not know how many columns the default table or userdef table have? I know they will have the same # of columns but the amount of columns is unknown.

Comment: @RolandP Try option B ans leave the *. If both tables have same columns that should work. Although it is not good practice to use `SELECT * ` - You should try to name your columns always.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately the columns are dynamic and can be either added or removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.CaseID, 
       ISNULL(td.data, tu.data) userData -- pick data from table_default
                                         -- if not null else from table_user
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_default td ON t1.CaseID = td.CaseID -- left join with table_default
                            AND t1.Boolean = 0        -- when boolean = 0
  LEFT JOIN table_user tu ON t1.CaseID = tu.CaseID -- left join with table_user
                         AND t1.Boolean = 1        -- when boolean = 1
  ORDER BY t1.CaseID
```